# Intro to C: Continuous Prompt for Input

Tags: c, loops, prompt

I want to make a code in ANSI C that prompts the user for a input.
First, I want to print the prompt.
Then, I want to echo the prompt and loop, ONLY if a character is typed and echoed.

I know that to make an infinite loop, I have to set the condition of while() into something that is always true, like while(1)

However, when I test my code, it seems that I loop printing "Enter a character" over and over again. Any tips for a newbie to C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char mychar;

while(1)
    printf("Enter a characater:\n");
    scanf("%c", &mychar);
    printf("%c", &mychar)
}
```

Comment: `printf("%c", mychar);`

Comment: You can use `getchar()` and `putchar()` instead....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blocks in C are not based on indenting (like in python, for example). Block must start with `{` and end with `}`, like this:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter a characater:\n");
    scanf("%c", &mychar);
    printf("%c", mychar);// NOTE the missing `&` in front of `mychar` here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an editor or an IDE which can autoformat/autoindent entire source files. If you had such a thing, you would have immediately seen the problem, because your code would look like this:

```
int main()
{
  char mychar;

  while(1)
    printf("Enter a characater:\n");
  scanf("%c", &mychar);
  printf("%c", &mychar)
}
```

And this is a mistake even experienced C programmers sometimes make, so having the simple cure (autoindent/autoformat code) for it is important even in future.

---

Unrelated problem, you pass pointer to char for `%c` format specifier in your latter `printf`. You should enable warnings on your compiler, it would warn you about that.